# segment to change the name of the text

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out the problem I have when I try to use the segment to change the name of the text in each scrolling.
I'm glad if anyone has a good idea for it and can help me.

**FirstViewController.swift**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController ,ScrollUISegmentControllerDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label3: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var segment: ScrollUISegmentController!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        segment.segmentDelegate = self
        segment.tag = 1
        segment.segmentItems = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
    }

    func selectItemAt(index: Int, onScrollUISegmentController scrollUISegmentController: ScrollUISegmentController) {
        print("select Item At\(index) in scrollUISegmentController with tag  \(scrollUISegmentController.tag) ")

    }

    @IBAction func SegeValueChange(_ sender: Any) {
        if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            Label1.text = " 100 "
            Label2.text = " 40 "
            Label3.text = " 400 "
        }
        if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
            Label1.text = " 100 "
            Label2.text = " 50 "
            Label3.text = " 400 "
        }
        if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {
            Label1.text = " 100 "
            Label2.text = " 60 "
            Label3.text = " 600 "
        }
    }
}
```

**ScrollUISegmentController.swift**

```
//
//  ScrollUISegmentController.swift
//  ScrollUISegmentController
//
//  Created by Ali Adam on 8/3/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Ali Adam. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

protocol ScrollUISegmentControllerDelegate: class {
    func selectItemAt(index :Int, onScrollUISegmentController scrollUISegmentController:ScrollUISegmentController)
}

@IBDesignable
class ScrollUISegmentController: UIScrollView  {
   private var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()

    weak var segmentDelegate: ScrollUISegmentControllerDelegate?

    @IBInspectable
    public var segmentTintColor: UIColor = .black {
        didSet {
            self.segmentedControl.tintColor = self.segmentTintColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    public var itemWidth: CGFloat = 100 {
        didSet {
        }
    }

    public var segmentFont: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13) {
        didSet {
            self.segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: self.segmentFont],for: UIControlState())
        }
    }

    public var itemsCount: Int = 3
    public var segmentheight : CGFloat = 29.0

    public var segmentItems: Array = ["1","2","3"] {
        didSet {
            self.itemsCount = segmentItems.count
            self.createSegment()
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        createSegment()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createSegment()
    }

    init(frame: CGRect , andItems items:[String]) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.segmentItems = items
        self.itemsCount = segmentItems.count
        self.createSegment()
    }

    func createSegment() {
        self.segmentedControl.removeFromSuperview()
        segmentheight =  self.frame.height
        var width = CGFloat(self.itemWidth * CGFloat(self.itemsCount))
        if width < self.frame.width {
            itemWidth =  CGFloat(self.frame.width) / CGFloat(itemsCount)
             width = CGFloat(self.itemWidth * CGFloat(self.itemsCount))
        }
        self.segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: width , height: segmentheight))
        self.addSubview(self.segmentedControl)
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.segmentedControl, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.segmentedControl, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        let contentHeight =  self.frame.height
        self.contentSize = CGSize (width: width, height: contentHeight)
        self.segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: self.segmentFont],for: UIControlState())
        self.segmentedControl.tintColor = self.segmentTintColor
        self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        insertItems()
        self.segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.segmentChangeSelectedIndex(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    }

    func insertItems(){
        for item in segmentItems {
            self.segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: item, at: (segmentItems.index(of: item))!, animated: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func segmentChangeSelectedIndex(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        segmentDelegate?.selectItemAt(index: self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex, onScrollUISegmentController: self)
        print("\(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)")
    }
}
```

I have this error:

> Value of type 'ScrollUISegmentController' has no member 'selectedSegmentIndex'

Comment: Maybe use `selectItemAt` to track when the selection changes and maintain the value in another instance field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using third party ScrollUISegmentController. You have to implement the delegate method to get selected index

```
 func selectItemAt(index: Int, onScrollUISegmentController scrollUISegmentController: ScrollUISegmentController) {
    if index== 1 {
    Label1.text = " 100 "
    Label2.text = " 40 "
    Label3.text = " 400 "
}
if index == 2 {
    Label1.text = " 100 "
    Label2.text = " 50 "
    Label3.text = " 400 "
}
if index == 3 {
    Label1.text = " 100 "
    Label2.text = " 60 "
    Label3.text = " 600 "
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find your `ScrollUISegmentController`, there is private variable of `UISegmentedControl` named `segmentedControl`, please remove `private` from there.

Now you can access `selectedSegmentIndex` using `segment.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex`.

Hope it works.

**UPDATE**

or you can create this property in `ScrollUISegmentController` like this,

```
var selectedIndex: Int {
    return self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
}
```

then you can access it like `segment.selectedIndex`

It works pretty. Take a look.